# Assigning strings from a list/array to multiples TextBox using foreach

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015, mysql-connector

It is my first question here and I'll try to be clear. I've taken 3 hours++ trying to find a solution and made tons of google searches.

To start, here's the relevant part of my code:

**DBHelper**

```
public List<string> mylist;
```

**Form1**

```
while (dbhelper.myReader.Read())            
       dbhelper.mylist.Add(dbhelper.myReader.GetString("Nom_Equipe"));
```

**Form2**

```
TextBox[] textboxlist1 = {dueltbTeam1, dueltbTeam2, dueltbTeam3, dueltbTeam4, dueltbTeam5, dueltbTeam6, dueltbTeam7, dueltbTeam8};

    foreach (TextBox textbox in textboxlist1)
            {
                 Action<string> entry;
                 entry = f => Assign(textbox, f);
                 dbhelper.mylist.ForEach(entry);
            }

    private static void Assign(TextBox s, string f)
            {
                s.Text = f;
            }
```

I made sure the "dbhelper.mylist" was still populated by content in form2, it still contain the 8 teams of my mysql database, so it isnt a problem. i was also able to make each TextBox show a single team name, the same in each TextBox. but i need to show one time each team, one team per Textbox. i used

```
foreach (string teamname in dbhelper.mylist)
                {
                    foreach (TextBox textbox in textboxlist1)
                    {
                        textbox.Text = teamname;
                    }
                }
```

Which shown a single team, the same one, in every textbox successfully, but I need to see different teams.

Forgive my English, I'm French. If I need to precise anything, I'll do it as soon as possible. Thanks!

Edit: I have the same amount of entries in textboxlist1 as in dbhelper.mylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have the same number of `teamNames` as records in `textBoxList1`.

```
for(int i=0; i<dbhelper.mylist.Length -1; i++)
{
    textboxlist1[i].Text = dbhelper.mylist[i];
}
```

If you don't have the same number of elements in `textboxlist1` and `dbhelper.mylist`, you should see which one of this arrays has smaller length and you should loop by this length.

Comment: Thank you, ill give it a try, and come back to say if it helped. i do have the same number of elements in textboxlist1 as dbhelper.mylist. ill edit the question. Thanks

Comment: YAY! Thank you my friend, it worked like a charm. i cant believe i missed something this simple, im new at working with lists and array. Much thanks! edit: accepted your awnser. have a nice day

Comment: @TommyPrudhomme it happens, mark the answer as correct and good luck with your project :)